# Populate UICollectionView from left to right when scrolling direction is horizontal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When scrolling direction is horizontal cells are added in `UICollectionView` from top to bottom
[image]

For scrolling direction = vertical, they are added from left to right.
[image]

The question is, if there is any way to add cells from left to right when scrolling direction is horizontal ?

Comment: Why not set the `itemSize` of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the way cells are added to the collection view

Comment: If the `height` of the `itemSize` is enough large so one column will has only one item

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same troubles

Comment: @alex_izh yes. I'll post an answer later

Comment: @gottlieb post an answer plz

Comment: @azimov Do you have a solution? I really need this right now :D

Comment: Up what is the solution please

Answer (score 2):

The order is automatically generated by the scroll direction, which is set by default. [image: figure]

What you can do is to add a custom layout for the UICollectionView by using the layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath method to set a frame for each individual cell.

```
-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(/* calculate your origin x */,
                                  /* calculate your origin y */,
                                  /* calculate your width */,
                                  /* calculate your height */);
    attr.frame = cellFrame;

    return attr;
}
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1)

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set the `scrollDirection` property to

```
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

Default setting is is vertical (top to bottom)

Comment: This is not the answer. He's how to populate the cells from left to right while maintaining horizontal scrolling.